# is there any c++ cross-platform parallel for-each loop?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, foreach, parallel-processing, cross-platform

is there any cross platform parallel c++ for-each loop like the one in the The Parallel Patterns Library? which is parallel_for_each which is and if i'm not mistaken ... a MS Windows only library ?

P.S: android and ios are included too when i said cross platform.

Answer (score 0):

As of standardized solutions, there is a ["C++ Extensions for Parallelism, ISO/IEC TS 19570:2015"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4507.pdf). It's not a part of the standard proper (yet), but a separate TS (Technical Specification). It is proposed for merge into C++17. It has parallel versions of several standard library algorithms. Unfortunately, it is not implemented yet in any compiler/standard library I am aware of.

Using Parallel TS, code will look like this ([see reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/parallelism)):

```
#include <experimental/algorithm>

std::experimental::parallel::for_each(std::experimental::parallel::par, first, last, op)
// specifies parallel execution policy                             ^^^
```